# VueJS. Module parse failed: Unexpected token <

Tags: vue.js, jsx, babel-loader

One of my `.vue` scripts has this import statement:

```js
import ElSlider from 'element-ui/packages/slider/src/main.vue'
```

The problem is, when it compiles, it throws an error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/element-ui/packages/slider/src/marker.js 13:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|     return (
>       <div class="el-slider__marks-text" style={ this.mark.style || {} }>
|         { label }
|       </div>
```

As you can see, the source code contains these lines:

```
 return (
 <div class="el-slider__marks-text" style={ this.mark.style || {} }>
 { label }
 </div>
```

And it seems, that Vue by default does not like this syntax. I tried to specify a loader in `vue.config.js` like so:

```js
   ...
   chainWebpack: config => {

    config.module
    .rule('jsx')
    .test(/marker\.js$/)
    .use('babel-loader')
    .loader('babel-loader')
    .tap(options => {
      options.presets = ["jsx", "es2015"]
      return options
    })
```

But it does not help. If it matters, I also modified `babel.config.js`. So it now looks like:

```js
 module.exports = {
   presets: ["@vue/app", "@vue/babel-preset-jsx", "es2015"],
   plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
 }
```

But it has no effect. So, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to setup Babel for JSX, as Vue CLI already does that automatically. The problem is your Vue CLI project needs to be configured to transpile Element UI, which could be done with the [`transpileDependencies` config](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#transpiledependencies):

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ['element-ui']
}
```

Also remember to include the CSS for the slider:

```js
import ElSlider from 'element-ui/packages/slider/src/main.vue'
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/slider.css'
```

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me into the right direction for the same problem with another dependency: `vue-meta`. Just added `vue-meta` instead of `element-ui` and it built :)

Comment: just had the same problem after updating dependencies and this fixed it. Question - how did I suppose to know this option? I never used it before and unless you provided this answer here, how one supposed to fix it?